# Instruments doesn't continue after running from command line

Tags: ios, command-line, continuous-integration, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

When I run Instruments from the command line using this script

```
instruments -w <DEVICE_ID> -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate <PATH_TO_APP> -e UIASCRIPT <PATH_TO_SCRIPT> -e UIARESULTSPATH <RESULTS_PATH>
```

The app opens on the device but doesn't run the script. 
The Terminal cursor moves to the next line and it looks like it just freezes

[image]

Comment: There could be a whole host of reasons that it's not working. Are you able to profile and automate the app on this device using the Instruments GUI? If it doesn't work there, either, there may either be a problem with your Xcode installation, or your device isn't properly initialized for development use.

Comment: I am not able to test the app on the device using Instruments GUI. I just receive the .app file and must test it. Is it possible that I cant run UIAutomation tests on a app signed with a Enterprise Distribution certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign your app with a Developer Profile. The app wont run from the command line if you sign it with a Enterprise Profile